# How can I perform a similar UPDATE-WHERE statement on SparkSQL2.0?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I implement an SQL query like this, in SparkSQL 2.0 using DataFrames and Scala language? I've read a lot of posts but none of them seems to achieve what I need, or if you can point me one, would do. Here's the problem:

```
UPDATE table SET value = 100 WHERE id = 2
UPDATE table SET value = 70 WHERE id = 4
.....
```

Suppose that you have a table `table` with two columns like this:

```
id  | value 
--- | ---
  1 | 1
  2 | null
  3 | 3
  4 | null
  5 | 5
```

Is there a way to implement the above query, using map, match cases, UDFs or if-else statements? The values that I need to store in the `value` field are not sequential, so I have specific values to put there. I'm aware too that it is not possible to modify a immutable data when dealing with DataFrames. I have no code to share because I can't get it to work nor reproduce any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, it's very simple. You can use `when` and `otherwise`.

```scala
val pf = df.select($"id", when($"id" === 2, lit(100)).otherwise(when($"id" === 4, lit(70)).otherwise($"value")).as("value"))
```